# Android reading data from sqlite when oflline

Tags: android, sqlite, nullpointerexception, android-sqlite

I am storing all the data in sqlite database when i am online and then when i am offline i try read the stored database everytime.

```
 if(isOnline(getActivity()))

        {
            db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());
            getDataInAsyncTask();
            storeData(db);
            //db.close();
        }
        else
                    {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            try {
                db.openDataBase();
            } catch (SQLException sqle) {
                throw sqle;
            }
            getDataInDataBase(db);
            flag=0;
        }
```

in the else condition i.e offline mode i do db.openDataBase() to open/load earlier implemented database db during online mode

```
   public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{

        //Open the database
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);}
```

db.openDataBase gives nullpointerException

Where am i going wrong ? Is the approach of loading/opening back already constructed database db right ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never initialized the **db** object.

Put the line

> db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity());

before the if/else statement or inside the try/catch statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
  /*
   * intitlize object globaly
  **/
   db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity()); 
   if(isOnline(getActivity()))

    {
       /**
        *  look at these you are
        *  intialize object when is online
        */
        //db = new DataBaseHandler(getActivity()); 
        getDataInAsyncTask();
        storeData(db);
        //db.close();
    }
    else
                {

    Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No internet",
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        try {
            db.openDataBase();
        } catch (SQLException sqle) {
            throw sqle;
        }
        getDataInDataBase(db);
        flag=0;
    }
```